# Set value and trigger action when dropdown value is changed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have this React select dropdown:

```
const handleSyncList = () => {
    ......
};
const [exchangeId, setExchangeId] = useState('');

<select onSelect={e => setExchangeId(e.target.value)} onChange={handleSyncList}>
  <option value="">All Exchanges</option>
  {exchangesList.map(otherEntity => (
        <option value={otherEntity.exchangeId}>
          .......
        </option>
      ))
    : null}
</select>
```

I need to set the selected value to `exchangeId` and call `handleSyncList`.
Is it possible first to set the option value and then call `handleSyncList` using useEffect like this:

```
useEffect(callback, [dep])
```

Comment: You can just invoke it sequentially: `onSelect={e => { setExchangeId(e.target.value); handleSyncList(); } }`

Comment: I tested your proposal but looks like first `handleSyncList` is called then `etExchangeId`. The result is that next time when I change the dropdown value the proper search value is displayed. Any idea how I can prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `handleSyncList` as `useEffect` callback and  define `exchangeId` as one of `useEffect` dependencies, and whenver `exchangeId` updates, your `handleSyncList` will call with the update value of `exchangeId`, like this;

```js
const exchangesList = ['a','b','c']
const App = ()=> {
  const [exchangeId, setExchangeId] = React.useState('');
   const handleSyncList = () => {
        console.log(exchangeId); // or whatever else
   };
  React.useEffect(handleSyncList , [exchangeId]);

   return (
     <select onChange={e => setExchangeId(e.target.value)}>
      <option value="">All Exchanges</option>
      {exchangesList.map(otherEntity => (
            <option value={otherEntity}>
              {otherEntity}
            </option>
          ))
       }
    </select>
   )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Consider that, in this manner `handleSync` will call in the first render, you can controll it by checking that `exchangeId` has value or not, or you can define a variable by react `useRef` and controll that is the first render of component or not, like this:

```
...
const [exchangeId, setExchangeId] = React.useState('');
const isMounted = React.useRef(false);
const handleSyncList = () => {
  if(isMounted.current){
   console.log(exchangeId); // or whatever else
  }
};
React.useEffect(handleSyncList , [exchangeId]);
React.useEffect(()=> { isMounted.current = true } , []);
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but you have to make sure you only run it, when `exchangeId` is changed, so you have to store previous `exchangeId` value somewhere, ideally in ref.

```
const [exchangeId, setExchangeId] = useState('');
const lastExchangeId = useRef(exchangeId);

//...

useEffect(() => {
  if (exchangeId !== lastExchangeId.current) {
    handleSyncList();
    lastExchangeId.current = exchangeId;
  }
}, [exchangeId])
```

Answer (score 1):

i cant' comment the post
I propose to use the useState callback just after setting the state

<select onChange={e => setExchangeId(e.target.value, () => handleSyncList()}>

Answer (score 0):

```js
useEffect(() => {
if(exchangeId !== "") handleSyncList()
},[exchangeId])
```

it will guarantee the order you want.

Comment: Do I need to update the dropdown code also?

Comment: This will also run `handleSyncList` automatically when component is mounted

Comment: @user1285928  <select onChange={e => setExchangeId(e.target.value)}>
will work

Comment: @BorisTB I edited the code to avoid handleSyncList() run when component is first mounted